# MySQL, How can i make this query faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a query that needs to connect 4 large tables.

**The tables:**

Table_1 (ID, active, price1, price2, name, category1, category2)
*This is the main table that has all the products, 32561 rows*

table_2 (ID, table_1_ID, room, stock)
*This is the table that contains the stock of the products in table_1, this table can have table_1.ID multiple times, 190400 rows*

table_3 (ID, table_1_ID, images)
*This table contains more info about a product like images, some products don't have them, 6546 rows*

table_4 (table_1_ID, view, type)
*This table contains views of products (views per month)*

**What i want:**

I'm trying to make a query that displays 20 of the top viewed products.

**Conditions:**

1. It can only display products that are in table_1.category1 (A,B,C,D,E)
2. It can only display products that are active='T'
3. It can only display products that are in room LJ0001 and MS0001
4. It can only display products that have at least 1 stock

**The code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Table_1.ID), Table_1.price1, Table_1.price2
   , Table_1.name, Table_1.category2, Table_3.images 
FROM Table_1 
   LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID=Table_2.table_1_ID 
   LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_1.ID=table_3.table_1_ID 
   LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_1.ID=table_4.table_1_ID 
WHERE Table_1.active='T' 
   AND (Table_1.category1 LIKE 'A%' 
        OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'B%' 
        OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'C%' 
        OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'D%' 
        OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'E%'
       ) 
   AND table_2.room IN ('LJ0001','MS0001') 
   AND table_2.stock!=0 
ORDER BY table_4.view DESC, Table_1.name 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

**Note:**

The code above works. But it take a while. I'm looking for any fixes that could make this faster.

Any help would be nice!
Thanks in advance.

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED**

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxvJ2.png)

Comment: What indexes do you have on the different tables? Index matter a lot in regards to this. Do you use foreign keys?

Comment: Start by showing us the indexes on each table, not simply the columns; and then do an EXPLAIN of the query, and show the results of that to see which indexes the query is using

Comment: You may need to add some indexes. Use `explain extended` with your final query to figure out what would be best to index.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function.

Comment: @h2ooooooo the foreign keys are: Table_2 (table_1_ID), Table_3 (table_1_ID), Table_4 (table_1_ID)

Answer (score 1):

Use the updated query below:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT Table_1.ID, Table_1.price1, Table_1.price2
, Table_1.name, Table_1.category2, Table_3.images 
FROM Table_1 
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID=Table_2.table_1_ID 
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_1.ID=table_3.table_1_ID 
LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_1.ID=table_4.table_1_ID 
WHERE Table_1.active='T' 
AND (Table_1.category1 = 'A' 
    OR Table_1.category1 = 'B' 
    OR Table_1.category1 = 'C' 
    OR Table_1.category1 = 'D' 
    OR Table_1.category1 = 'E'
    ) 
AND table_2.room IN ('LJ0001','MS0001') 
AND table_2.stock != 0 
ORDER BY table_4.view DESC, Table_1.name 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I deleted `DISTINCT` because I assumed that `table_1.ID` is a primary key. If so,there is no need to use `DISTINCT` with primary keys because it's already distinct. I also changed the `LIKE` operator to `=` it because it works faster.

Then you need to make sure that all join fields such as `table_1_ID` have been indexed.

And you may notice `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on the top of the query - with this clause you will get something like this from the db:

```
           id: 1
           select_type: PRIMARY
           table: t1
           type: index
           possible_keys: NULL
           key: PRIMARY
           key_len: 4
           ref: NULL
           rows: 4
           filtered: 100.00
           Extra: Using index
```

You will get the description for each table. All foreign keys used in the query will be listed, including details like if the foreign key has index, etc. You will find more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html).

Comment: i'll check the indexes if there's a problem. I think table_4 has some problems regarding that. I'm gonna need the LIKE part because the table_1.category1 look like this: (A.01.001, A.01.002, A.01.003....)

Comment: I suggest to make `categories` table and use `category_id` instead of that

Comment: Unfortunately i can't. The tables (table_1 and table_2) are preset by the company's program and i have to use what i've got...

Answer (score 0):

I think my fixes can help you. if you can set sql_cache_type = 2 in my.cnf you should use SQL_CACHE in query (if there are not fields with text type) and it is better first do conditions which are "easier" for DB (LIKE with OR are very slow), if you use INNODB you can set a larger  buffer pool for MySQL

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE DISTINCT(Table_1.ID), Table_1.price1, Table_1.price2
, Table_1.name, Table_1.category2, Table_3.images 
FROM Table_1 
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.ID=Table_2.table_1_ID 
LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_1.ID=table_3.table_1_ID 
LEFT JOIN table_4 ON table_1.ID=table_4.table_1_ID 
WHERE Table_1.active='T' 
 AND table_2.stock!=0 
 AND table_2.room IN ('LJ0001','MS0001') 
 AND (Table_1.category1 LIKE 'A%' 
    OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'B%' 
    OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'C%' 
    OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'D%' 
    OR Table_1.category1 LIKE 'E%'
   ) 
ORDER BY table_4.view DESC, Table_1.name 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Ok, the change of conditions helped a bit making the dispay a bit faster!

Comment: @MarkoMihalič check out caching if you can use it

Comment: I've noticed that the facebook plugin is sloving down the loading as well, i'm using jQuery LOAD function to load in the SQL query above.